Laravel: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I can't upload my file when using Laravel (filamentphp + tenancyforlaravel packages).
I tried deleting the entire app cache, running the composer dump-autoload command again and setting permissions for the storage folder.
Thanks all!

This is a file permission issue, You need to change your tenant{id} folder permission with 777(read and create) and create manually framework/cache folder inside tenant{id} folder to fix this error.
